# Failed to ref to Appendix with alphabet

Tags: cross-referencing, appendix

I am following template .cls and .tex files to write my thesis, everything works fine until I want to reference to my Appendix. It shows as Appendix 6, instead of Appendix A. Here is the related code about appendix.

```
% appendix.tex

\chapter{Appendix A: 1st appendix}
\label{appendix:a} 
\phantopsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A: 1st appendix}
```

```
% template.cls

\newcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}

\newcommand\appendixname{Appendix}
```

The table of content and heading are '*Appendix A: 1st appendix*', which is expected. However `Appendix \ref{appendix:a}` gives '*Appendix 6*' (I have 6 chapters in total) instead of '*Appendix A*'.

**What I have tried**

I felt strange that the template does not use `\appendix` at all, especially I've come across many solutions here that indicate it can resolve the issue. So I added `\appendix` and remove the `*` from `\chapter`.

```
% new_appendix.tex

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix A: 1st appendix}
```

Now `Appendix \ref{appendix:a}` gives '*Appendix A*' correctly, but there is a chapter Heading '*Chapter A*' above '*Appendix A: 1st appendix*'. Also, the table of content becomes '*1 Appendix A: 1st appendix*'.

As far as I can understand, the `\newcommand\appendix` already tried to change the Chapter name to Appendix, and use alphabet instead of number as index. However the command is not effective and I cannot figure out why.

**What I want**

- Heading and table of content show as '*Appendix A: 1st appendix*'
- Can be referenced as 'Appendix A'

I have tried to switch to `\documentclass[]{report}` and the Appendix works as expected, I believe there is something wrong with the `template.cls`. Please help to correct the `\newcommand` content (or the `appendix.tex`).

Thank you very much!

p.s. Addition info that may be useful: `fancyhdr` and `hyperref` is used. If necessary I can post the full list of packages used.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The `bookcls` defined `\appendix` in such a way that the counter is reset, and chapter "numbers" are changed to `\Alph`.  (I don't remember what's done for `report`.)  So if you have to define `\appendix`, best to look in `book.cls` for a model.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hi! I was also thinking to take a look at `report.cls` as I found that it can do the work. However I cannot find the file anywhere online. Do you know if there is any online version of these default .cls files? Thank you!

Comment: `report.cls` is part of the "required" latex distributiion, but it's not separately present on ctan, and I never remember the name of the `.dtx` file from which it's generated.  What I'd do is create a stupid "Hello world" file using `report`, process it, then look in the log file to find where to look for the `.cls` file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I am using online editor (overleaf) to write my thesis. I guess your way is not applicable to the editor :( But thank you for your reply anyway!